# Why is GUI responsiveness impaired by a Worker thread?

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-multithreading, qthread, qrunnable

I'm trying to understand why this `Worker` thread, which deliberately uses a fairly intense amount of processing (sorting of these dictionaries in particular) causes the GUI thread to become unresponsive. Here is an MRE:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys, time, datetime, random

def time_print(msg):
    ms_now = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(sep=' ', timespec='milliseconds')
    thread = QtCore.QThread.currentThread()
    print(f'{thread}, {ms_now}: {msg}')
    
def dict_reorder(dictionary):
    return {k: v for k, v in sorted(dictionary.items())}
    
class Sequence(object):
    n_sequence = 0
    simple_sequence_map = {}
    sequence_to_sequence_map = {}
    prev_seq = None
    
    def __init__(self):
        Sequence.n_sequence += 1 
        if Sequence.n_sequence % 1000 == 0:
            print(f'created sequence {Sequence.n_sequence}')
        rand_int = random.randrange(100000)
        self.text = str(rand_int)
        Sequence.simple_sequence_map[self] = rand_int
        if Worker.stop_ordered:
            time_print(f'init() A: stop ordered... stopping now')
            return
        dict_reorder(Sequence.simple_sequence_map)
        if Sequence.prev_seq:
            Sequence.sequence_to_sequence_map[self] = Sequence.prev_seq
            if Worker.stop_ordered:
                time_print(f'init() B: stop ordered... stopping now')
                return
            dict_reorder(Sequence.sequence_to_sequence_map)
        Sequence.prev_seq = self

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.text < other.text    
        
class WorkerSignals(QtCore.QObject):
    progress = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    stop_me = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

class Worker(QtCore.QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()
        
    def stop_me_slot(self):
        time_print('stop me slot')    
        Worker.stop_ordered = True
    
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        total_n = 30000
        Worker.stop_ordered = False
        for n in range(total_n):
            progress_pc = int(100 * float(n+1)/total_n)
            self.signals.progress.emit(progress_pc)
            Sequence()
            if Worker.stop_ordered:
                time_print(f'run(): stop ordered... stopping now, n {n}')
                return

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.progress = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        layout.addWidget(self.progress)
        
        start_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start')
        start_button.pressed.connect(self.execute)
        layout.addWidget(start_button)
        
        self.stop_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Stop')
        layout.addWidget(self.stop_button)
        
        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        self.show()
        self.threadpool = QtCore.QThreadPool()
        self.resize(800, 600)

    def execute(self):
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.signals.progress.connect(self.update_progress)
        self.stop_button.pressed.connect(self.worker.stop_me_slot)
        self.threadpool.start(self.worker)
        
    def update_progress(self, progress):
        self.progress.setValue(progress)        
              
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

On my machine, up until about 12%, the GUI is significantly unresponsive: the buttons do not acquire their "hover-over" colour (light blue) and seem not to be able to be clicked (although clicking "Stop" does cause stop after many seconds). Intermittently the dreaded spinner appears (blue circle in a W10 OS).

After 12% or so it becomes possible to use the buttons normally.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution is to "sleep" the thread by using a basic `time.sleep`: even with a very small interval, it will give enough time for the main thread to process its event queue avoiding UI locking:

```
    def run(self):
        total_n = 30000
        Worker.stop_ordered = False
        for n in range(total_n):
            progress_pc = int(100 * float(n+1)/total_n)
            self.signals.progress.emit(progress_pc)
            Sequence()
            if Worker.stop_ordered:
                time_print(f'run(): stop ordered... stopping now, n {n}')
                return
            time.sleep(.0001)
```

<sup>Note: that `pyqtSlot` decorator is useless, because it only works for QObject subclasses (which QRunnable isn't); you can remove it.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Python cannot run more than one CPU-intensive thread. The cause of it the the [GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/). Basically Python threads are not good for anything but waiting for I/O.

If you want a CPU-intensive part, try either rewriting the intensive part [using Cython](https://lbolla.info/python-threads-cython-gil.html), or use `multiprocessing`, but then the time to send data back and forth could be significant.

Comment: Thanks! This is a really helpful clue. I'm just a bit surprised that the GUI thread is classed as a "CPU-intensive thread". Perhaps you mean, more accurately, that if there is ONE CPU-intensive thread it can't in practice co-exist with ANY other threads in that same process?

Comment: I'm inclined to look to rewrite in Rust... which for a couple of years now seems to be the new sexy kid on the block. It is deliberately designed with multithreading in mind, and apparently Qt bindings are available.

Comment: @mikerodent: A GUI thread can unfortunately be CPU-sensitive. that is, to require enough CPU _at the right time_ to not feel choppy. musicamante above suggested a solution just for that: yield control from the CPU-intensive thread so that the GUI thread had a chance to proceed more often.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce, ui stays responsive even with limited resources. Have you tried to run it without debugger?

GIL may be the problem as @9000 suggests.

Or maybe eventloop flooded with `progress` signals, try to emit it less than one for each sequence.

As a sidenote: program works faster if you dont throw away sorting results every time with `dict_reorder`.
try to replace

```
dict_reorder(Sequence.simple_sequence_map)
```

with

```
Sequence.simple_sequence_map = dict_reorder(Sequence.simple_sequence_map)
```

and

```
dict_reorder(Sequence.sequence_to_sequence_map)
```

with

```
Sequence.sequence_to_sequence_map = dict_reorder(Sequence.sequence_to_sequence_map)
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. I cut down the progress signals by `if n % 100 == 0:` and the problem appears solved! In fact I wasn't looking for a way to optimise this dictionary sorting: I actually spent a bit of time finding something (similar to my real project) which is deliberately very intensive. You say that even with all the progress signals you don't have a problem. Could you say what OS you are on?  Is your machine particularly high-spec? This one is an i7-7700 3.6 GHz with large RAM etc.

Comment: For that matter, what do you mean by "run it without the debugger"? I just googled this and I'm not quite clear... I'm just running `python my_package` at the CLI. Is there a debugger as standard with Python which you have to actively turn off? (pardon my ignorance if so...)

Comment: @mikerodent I thought you run it in ide with debugger attached, but you run it in terminal so no debugger involved. I run it on win7 on not modern notebook (Core i7 4510U) in power saving settings mode alongside cpu intensive video encoder process (and without it) and had no freezes, I run it in win10 (Core i5 4590) and only had few one-second lags sometimes.